# Using form to insert a link into the current cell

Tags: excel, vba

for some reason I'm having a lot more trouble than expected setting the anchor for a link as the active cell in this piece of code. I want to use this form so that people can use it to insert a link that they define, and a caption that they define into their selected cell. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Insert_Click()

    With ActiveSheet
     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range(ActiveCell), _
     Address:="" & TextBox2 & "", _
     ScreenTip:="Ay yo fam what it do?", _
     TextToDisplay:="" & TextBox1 & ""
    End With

InsertLink.Hide
Unload InsertLink

End Sub
```

Comment: (a) FWIW `Range(ActiveCell)` is probably meant to be `ActiveCell` (unless you intend to retrieve the value from the ActiveCell and then treat that as a range name/address (e.g. if the `ActiveCell` contained "G5" then you would be setting the anchor to be cell G5)  (b) What do you mean "I'm having a lot more trouble than expected" - what is not working?  What errors (if any) do you get? (c) Also FWIW - get out of the habit of using expressions such as `"" & TextBox1 & ""` - if you want to ensure `TextBox1` is treated as a `String` then explicitly cast it using `CStr(TextBox1)`.

Comment: Hi YowE3K - I had tried ActiveCell before, and it didn't work. I retried it just then and it seems to have worked this time. I must have had an unexpected character in the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Source Code

```
Private Sub Insert_Click()

Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveCell

    With ActiveSheet
         .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:="" & TextBox2 & "", _
     ScreenTip:="Ay yo fam what it do?", _
     TextToDisplay:="" & TextBox1 & ""
    End With

InsertLink.Hide
Unload InsertLink

End Sub
```

Comment: you should provide at least a brief explanation of your answer.